# Mocking an API request for downstream module using Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am a beginner when it comes to writing tests and mocking.

I have a created two modules. One module object (Site) creates another object from my second module (Item) on init. The Item object makes a call to an API endpoint to get some data using `requests`.

I want to Mock the API call I am making so I can test things like a bad response and importantly have control over the response data.

I have simplified my code and put below. When I run the test I get back the actual response data and not what I have mocked.

I have a feeling I am not putting my Mock in the right place. Also, I have seen lots of people saying to use @unittest.patch annotation. I am not clear if I should be using that here.

So I am looking for how to get `_get_range_detail` to actually return a Mocked response from `requests` and also just general feedback on if it looks like I am approaching this the right way.

```
# hello_world.py

from mymodule.site import Site

sites = [
    dict(
        name="site1",
        ranges=[
            "range1",
            "range2"
        ]
    )
]


site_object = Site(sites[0]['name'], sites[0]['ranges'])
for i in site_object.get_ranges_objects():
    print(i.range_detail)
```

```
# site.py

from mymodule.item import Item

class Site:

    def __init__(self, name, ranges):

        self.name = name
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ranges_objects = []
        for my_range in ranges:
            self.ranges_objects.append(Item(my_range))

    def get_ranges_objects(self):

        return self.ranges_objects
```

```
# item.py

import requests

class Item:

    def __init__(self, range_name):

        self.range_name = range_name
        self.range_detail = self._get_range_detail(self.range_name)

    def _get_range_detail(self, range_name):

        uri = "https://postman-echo.com/get?some_cool_value=real_value"
        try:
            r = requests.get(uri)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                return r.json()['args']
            else:
                return None
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            exit(1)
```

```
# test_site.py

import pytest
from mymodule.site import Site
from unittest import mock
from mymodule.item import requests

def test_get_ranges_objects():

    sites = [
        dict(
            name="site1",
            ranges=[
                "range1",
                "range2"
            ]
        )
    ]

    requests = mock.Mock()
    requests.status_code = 200
    requests.json.return_value = {
        'args': {'some_mock_value': 'mocky'}
    }

    site_object = Site(sites[0]['name'], sites[0]['ranges'])
    assert site_object.name == "site1"
    assert isinstance(site_object.ranges_objects, list)
    assert site_object.ranges_objects[0].range_detail == dict(some_mock_value='mocky')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytest-mock. it makes mocking in pytest simple. (pip install pytest-mock)
You should replace requests.get. Simply

```py
requests_get = mock.patch('requests.get').start()
```

If you use pytest-mock,

```py
requests_get = mocker.patch('requests.get')
```

Rewrote test case using pytest-mock

```py
# test_site.py

import pytest
from mymodule.site import Site
from unittest import mock


@pytest.fixture
def requests_get(mocker):
    requests_get = mocker.patch('requests.get')
    yield requests_get


def test_get_ranges_objects(mocker, requests_get):

    response = mocker.MagicMock()
    response.status_code = 200
    response.json.return_value = {'args': {'some_mock_value': 'mocky'}}
    requests_get.return_value = response

    sites = [
        dict(
            name="site1",
            ranges=[
                "range1",
                "range2"
            ]
        )
    ]

    site_object = Site(sites[0]['name'], sites[0]['ranges'])
    assert site_object.name == "site1"
    assert isinstance(site_object.ranges_objects, list)
    assert site_object.ranges_objects[0].range_detail == {'some_mock_value': 'mocky'}
```

Comment: Note that you can do the same with the standard `unittest.mock` by using the decorator `@mock.patch('mymodule.item.requests')`.

Comment: So for clarification...

The fixture uses mocker.patch on 'requests.get' so this means any time requests.get is called in the function that has this fixture applied it will instead use the mock?  Why do you use yield rather than just return?  I thought yields were for big lists?

If the details I was setting in `response` was common across multiple tests could I just include it as part of the fixture?